# Where can we ask R programming related questions that demands theoretical answer?

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes we don't have coding issue. We are just curious about it? For example I have question,

The complete list of models is available here
[Caret Model List](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html)

- Which are the most frequently used?
- Model selection criteria is hard to remember, is there any simpler way to use specific models on specific situations?
- Are there any measures which describes xyz model is powerful than others?

I am new to stack overflow. I know these are too broad questions, but need HELP!

Comment: There is [a site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for that as well.

Comment: @Hans I am new so I did not know about cross validated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a replacement for actual research. *You* must do the research in these cases. One of the best skills obtained in formal education is the ability to self educate.

That means looking at existing resources related to your current issue, which happens to be the Caret Model list. Did you consult their documentation? It is quite extensive.

https://topepo.github.io/caret/

> Some resources:
>
> - The book *Applied Predictive Modeling* features **caret** and over 40 other R packages. It is on sale at [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461468485) or the [the publisher’s website](http://www.springer.com/statistics/life+sciences%2C+medicine+%26+health/book/978-1-4614-6848-6). There is a [companion website](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/) too.
> - There is also a paper on caret in the [Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05). The example data can be obtained here(the predictors) and here (the outcomes).
> - There is a [webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Jbb2ItbTC4) for the package on Youtube that was organized and recorded by Ray DiGiacomo Jr for the Orange County R User Group.
> - At [useR! 2014](http://user2014.stat.ucla.edu), I was [interviewed](http://youtu.be/YmHyAHkjX_A) and discussed the package and the book.
> - [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com) has a [beginner’s tutorial on machine learning in R](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/machine-learning-toolbox) using `caret`.
>
> You can always email me with questions,comments or suggestions.

Did you try any of those resources? I am certainly not going to email this person with regards to explaining these models to you, nor am I really willing to purchase a book to read in order to explain it.

I would assume that the community here wouldn't be inclined to either.

In the end, Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant. The best thing you can do in these instances is actually do the research yourself.

Comment: I know Stack Overflow is not my research assistant. With extensive resources, Google is overwhelming for newbies like me. However, I will refer it more now.  Thank You @Travis J. I have downloaded those videos and subscribed to the Youtube Channel.and I will study those by practicing with R!